# 購入画面でステータスが非公開の商品まで表示される。

Tags: php

自動販売機システムを作成しているのですが、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
購入画面でステータスが公開のみの商品を出したいにも関わらず、
非公開の商品まで表示されてしまいます。
require_onceを使ったり、if文を使ったりして表示を試みましたが、うまくいきません。
(下の画像のようになる。)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
"new_status"自体がtool2.phpの中で宣言されているので値をindex2.phpで使えるように連携する必要がありますが、そのやり方がいまいちわからないです。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。
ソースコード
Model
functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');

function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
            
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
        if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
             
             $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
        }
            
        }
        
            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, stock, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                return $err_msg;
                
                
            }
                
            }
    }


        
function update_drink($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

        if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
                $update_stock = (int)($_POST['update_stock']);

                $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;
                
                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                   $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                   return $err_msg;
                }
                }
        }
}




function change_drink($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

        if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
                $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
                $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

                $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
                return $err_msg;
            }
        }
    }
    
}



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
    FROM drink_info_table';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

function complete_check_insert($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_update($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_change($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_price']) || (isset($_POST['new_price']) && $_POST['new_price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_price'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_stock']) || (isset($_POST['new_stock']) && $_POST['new_stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_stock'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!empty($_POST["new_status"])) {
    if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 2) {
     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
    }
    }
return $err_msg;
}

function validation_check2($link) {
    if (!empty($_POST["update_stock"])) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['update_stock'])) !== 1){ 
     $err_msg = [];
     $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
     return $err_msg;
    }

}
}
```

Controller
index.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/index2.php');

close_db_connect($link);
```

View
tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');?>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ((array)$data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="renew" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" name="change" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit"  name="change" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

index2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <!--<?php foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>-->
    <!--    <P><?php print $err; ?></P>-->
    <!--<?php } ?>-->

    <h1>自動販売機</h1>

    <form class="form" method="post" action="include/view/result2.php">

        <div>
            金額 <input type="text" name="money" />
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
             <?php 
             if (!empty($data)) {
               foreach ((array)$data as $product) {
             
             ?>
                <? php print htmlspecialchars($product,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="product_name">
                        <p class="margin"><?php
                        if ("new_status" === "1") {
                        print $product['drink_name']; 
                        }
                       ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product_price">
                        <p class="margin"><?php
                         if ("new_status" === "1") {
                        print $product['price'];
                         }
                        ?>円</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product_buy">
                        <?php  if ("new_status" === "1") {
                        print $product['stock']; 
                        } ?>
                        <?php if ((int) $product['stock'] === 0) { ?>
                            <div class="sold_out"><?php print '売り切れ'; ?></div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                         <input type="radio" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $product['drink_id']; ?>" />
                        <?php } ?>

                           
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <div id="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□購入■□■□" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

その他
const.php

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];
$data = [];

define('DB_HOST',   '');
define('DB_USER',   '');
define('DB_PASSWD', '');
define('DB_NAME',   '');

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: `"new_status" === "1"`はどういう条件を書きたいのですか？

Answer (score 1):

function.php の do_sql でデータを取得しているかと思いますが、
ここの `SELECT` 文で WHERE 句を使って適切な条件で絞り込んでください。

例えば status = "公開" のみ表示する場合は以下のような記述になるかと思います。

```
function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_id, drink_name, price, stock, status
    FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1';
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。直してみます。